# Best way to export multiple PDF files with django as backend and React as frontend

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-celery

I am currently working on a web application which has django backend (using DRF) and React as frontend.

I want to create an API which can export multiple PDF files(of 4-5 pages each). Ofcourse, it will take a long time and doing it in normal HTTP request/response cycle will timeout.

What is the best way/architecture to incorporate this in the backend?

PS: I already have celery working for several other apis(time consuming background tasks) but in this case, I want response (i.e pdf files) from the celery to reach frontend. I am not sure how to do that.

Any other method which is ideal for such scenario is appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show the PDF to user in front and not email it later i think the best solution would be to tell the user you will notify them when the PDF is ready and generate PDFs in the background then notify the User's React front with a push notification(or some websock like SignalR) and perform an API to able the user to download the PDFs or just do the email thing

**Reason:**
you can't hold the request for a long time(I mean you can but its not appropriate ,no one wants to wait for a long time watching a white screen ,right?) so it must be done in the background